# Auto scroll to bottom of table

Tags: javascript, html

I followed the most popular solution, as follows:

```
let elem = document.getElementById("mytable");
elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
```

But it doesn't seem to work. `elem.scrollTop` always stays as `0`.

```js
let elem = document.getElementById("mytable");
elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.25;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
}

table caption {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: .5em 0 .75em;
}

table tr {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: .35em;
}

table th,
table td {
  padding: .625em;
  text-align: center;
}

table th {
  font-size: .85em;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  table {
    border: 0;
  }

  table caption {
    font-size: 1.3em;
  }
  
  table thead {
    border: none;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
  }
  
  table tr {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: .625em;
  }
  
  table td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    font-size: .8em;
    text-align: right;
  }
  
  table td::before {
    /*
    * aria-label has no advantage, it won't be read inside a table
    content: attr(aria-label);
    */
    content: attr(data-label);
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  
  table td:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="mytable">
  <caption>Statement Summary</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Account</th>
      <th scope="col">Due Date</th>
      <th scope="col">Amount</th>
      <th scope="col">Period</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-label="Account">Visa - 3412</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">04/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$1,190</td>
      <td data-label="Period">03/01/2016 - 03/31/2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Account">Visa - 6076</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$2,443</td>
      <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Account">Corporate AMEX</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$1,181</td>
      <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Account">Visa - 6076</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$2,443</td>
      <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Account">Corporate AMEX</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$1,181</td>
      <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Account">Visa - 6076</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$2,443</td>
      <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Account">Corporate AMEX</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$1,181</td>
      <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Account">Visa - 6076</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$2,443</td>
      <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Account">Corporate AMEX</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$1,181</td>
      <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Account">Visa - 6076</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$2,443</td>
      <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Account">Corporate AMEX</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$1,181</td>
      <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Account">Visa - 6076</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$2,443</td>
      <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Account">Corporate AMEX</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$1,181</td>
      <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Account">Visa - 6076</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$2,443</td>
      <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Account">Corporate AMEX</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$1,181</td>
      <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Account">Visa - 6076</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$2,443</td>
      <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Account">Corporate AMEX</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$1,181</td>
      <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Account">Visa - 6076</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$2,443</td>
      <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Account">Corporate AMEX</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$1,181</td>
      <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Account">Visa - 6076</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$2,443</td>
      <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Account">Corporate AMEX</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$1,181</td>
      <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Acount">Visa - 3412</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">02/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$842</td>
      <td data-label="Period">01/01/2016 - 01/31/2016</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this example:

```js
let elem = document.getElementById("mytable");
let btn = document.querySelector('button.scroll-to-table-end');
let btnSmooth = document.querySelector('button.smooth-scroll-to-table-end');


// Scroll to the end of the tabel when then button is clicked
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  window.scrollTo(0, elem.offsetHeight);
})


// Scroll to the end of the tabel SMOOTHLY when then button is clicked
btnSmooth.addEventListener('click', () => {
  window.scrollBy({ 
    top: elem.offsetHeight, // Scroll the the end of the tabele's height
    behavior: 'smooth' 
  });
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.25;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
}

table caption {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: .5em 0 .75em;
}

table tr {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: .35em;
}

table th,
table td {
  padding: .625em;
  text-align: center;
}

table th {
  font-size: .85em;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  table {
    border: 0;
  }

  table caption {
    font-size: 1.3em;
  }
  
  table thead {
    border: none;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
  }
  
  table tr {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: .625em;
  }
  
  table td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    font-size: .8em;
    text-align: right;
  }
  
  table td::before {
    /*
    * aria-label has no advantage, it won't be read inside a table
    content: attr(aria-label);
    */
    content: attr(data-label);
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  
  table td:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  
  <button class="scroll-to-table-end">Scroll to the end of table</button>
  <button class="smooth-scroll-to-table-end">Scroll to the end of table - Smooth</button>
  
<table id="mytable">
  <caption>Statement Summary</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Account</th>
      <th scope="col">Due Date</th>
      <th scope="col">Amount</th>
      <th scope="col">Period</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-label="Account">Visa - 3412</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">04/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$1,190</td>
      <td data-label="Period">03/01/2016 - 03/31/2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Account">Visa - 6076</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$2,443</td>
      <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Account">Corporate AMEX</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$1,181</td>
      <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Account">Visa - 6076</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$2,443</td>
      <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Account">Corporate AMEX</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$1,181</td>
      <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Account">Visa - 6076</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$2,443</td>
      <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Account">Corporate AMEX</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$1,181</td>
      <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Account">Visa - 6076</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$2,443</td>
      <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Account">Corporate AMEX</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$1,181</td>
      <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Account">Visa - 6076</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$2,443</td>
      <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Account">Corporate AMEX</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$1,181</td>
      <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Account">Visa - 6076</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$2,443</td>
      <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Account">Corporate AMEX</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$1,181</td>
      <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Account">Visa - 6076</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$2,443</td>
      <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Account">Corporate AMEX</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$1,181</td>
      <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Account">Visa - 6076</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$2,443</td>
      <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Account">Corporate AMEX</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$1,181</td>
      <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Account">Visa - 6076</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$2,443</td>
      <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Account">Corporate AMEX</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$1,181</td>
      <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Account">Visa - 6076</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$2,443</td>
      <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Account">Corporate AMEX</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$1,181</td>
      <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Acount">Visa - 3412</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">02/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$842</td>
      <td data-label="Period">01/01/2016 - 01/31/2016</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

You can user a [Pollyfill](http://iamdustan.com/smoothscroll/) if you need more [support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=scrollintoview).

Answer (score 2):

```
var rowpos = $('#table tr:last').position();

$('#container').scrollTop(rowpos.top);
```

it works for me ...

Comment: The best and most elegant answer so far! And Yes it works!